# In iOS7 is it possible to link from a button in an app directly to a moments page in the standard photo App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, photos

Please excuse what is no doubt a beginners question, but I'm wondering if it is possible to link directly from a button in an iOS7 app directly to a moments page within the iphones standard Photo app. 
ie that you press the button and the lastest videos moment page in the Photos app opens directly ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the solution to at least get to the photos app

```
NSString *stringURL = @"photos-redirect:";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```